# Show that two (p-1) th roots of unity cannot be congruent modulo p.

Tags: combinatorics, congruences

Show that two $(p-1)$ th roots of unity cannot be congruent modulo $p$.

I was thinking in this way:
That suppose two $(p-1)$th roots of unity $a_i, a_j$ are congruent to mod p.
Then 
 $a_i \equiv a_j$ mod $p$
Then we are end up with $1 \equiv 1$ mod $p$, which is true. Not able to find any contradiction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by congruent modulo $p$ in this case? $(p-1)$th roots of unity are complex numbers, and modulo $p$ only makes sense over $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

The $p-1$th roots of unity are $$\displaystyle e^{\dfrac{2\pi i r}{p-1}}$$ where $0\le r\le p-2$

$$\text{If  }\displaystyle e^{\dfrac{2\pi i r_1}{p-1}}\equiv e^{\dfrac{2\pi i r_2}{p-1}}\pmod p$$

$$e^{\dfrac{2\pi(r_2-r_1)i}{p-1}}\equiv1\pmod p$$

$$e^{\dfrac{2\pi(r_2-r_1)i}{p-1}}\equiv e^{2\pi i s}\pmod p$$ for some integer $s$

$$\displaystyle\implies \frac{r_2-r_1}{p-1}\equiv s\pmod{p-1}$$ as $\phi(p)=p-1$ which is impossible unless $s=0\iff r_2=r_1$ as $\displaystyle 0\le r\le p-2, |r_2-r_1|<p-1$

Comment: $\frac {r_2-r_1}{p-1} \equiv s$  ( mod $p-1)$ , why?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If $a_i \equiv a_j \pmod{p}$, then $p|(a_i-a_j)$.

Comment: So $a_i-a_j = px$ for some $x \in \mathbb Z $. Then?